# Convert date to milliseconds for highchart date

Tags: javascript, php, date, highcharts

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/

I'm working on above hight chart "Highstock - Single line series". But I'm stuck with the date format of Highstock - Single line series. the json format is showing the date format like '1162857600000'. how to convert date like 11/5/2013 to that format?

Is that milliseconds?

What I've already tried:

```
echo strtotime('11/05/2013')*1000; //It shows 1383606000000 means 11/4/2013.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is likely a timezone issue

Comment: What are you trying to, by multiplying by 1000?

Comment: Have you tried using `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` before using `strtotime()` ?

Comment: @AlexW I'm trying to convert datetime to milisecond that's why converting it by 1000

Comment: @AlexW do you mean echo date_default_timezone_set('11/05/2013'); its also throwing an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [date highstock highchart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211027/date-highstock-highchart)

Comment: @Tariq No. Don't use `echo`, just put this at the top of the PHP file: `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

Comment: @AlexW, Still same. Actually I want to get same date which highchart is using. I don't no how to convert date format same as high chart using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts use timestamps, but you can use javascript split function on string and then use Date.UTC().

Datepicker: http://jsfiddle.net/BWEm5/

```
 setTimeout(function() {
            $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#' + chart.options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker()
        }, 0)
```

Comment: how to send date using timestamps by jquery datepicker? so i would use it later to split the date using javascript

Comment: That is PERFECT. Thank you for your time. Spot on